# Where is the typo $\frac{2}{pq}=\frac{1}{p^{\frac{p+q}{2}}}+\frac{1}{q^{\frac{p+q}{2}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Where is the typo?

> Show that $\dfrac{2}{pq}=\dfrac{1}{p^{\frac{p+q}{2}}}+\dfrac{1}{q^{\frac{p+q}{2}}}$

I check with p=3 and q=5 and that doesn't hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typo is that at the denominator it should read $p\cdot \left(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\right)$ and the same for the other fraction.